# How to restore a Joomla 1.5 Akeeba Backup 3.4.3 site to a new server with SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, joomla, installation, migrate

Joomla 2.5 supports SQL Server, but I have an old site created in Joomla 1.5 that used Akeeba Backup 3.4.3 and MySQL.

When I navigate to the site for the first time, Akeeba Backup recognizes that the site needs to be installed, but it's not giving me the option of using MSSQL Server.

I tried dumping the newer Joomla 2.5 into the web directory, but that didn't help.  Does anyone know how I can migrate a Joomla 1.5 site that used MySQL to Joomla 2.5 using SQL Server?

Comment: You would need to do the upgrade on a server that has mysql. I would recommend doing the upgrade on your local machine using wamp or xampp (or similar apache, mysql, php system). Once the site is in 2.5, back it up again with akeeba and move it to the system with mssql.

Comment: It's all on the same server, I just want to get rid of MySQL and stick with SQL Server.  I think I will just use a software tool that does the migration from 1.5 to 3.0 automatically.  I have a good start with PHP 5.4 for IIS and a new folder with Joomla 3.0 installed and connected to SQL Server 2012.  My only concern is that the YooThemes (Phoenix) theme the site is using stops compatibility at 2.5, so I'll probably have to choose a new theme for Joomla 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

First, the old site had to be live with MySQL, so that I could upgrade it to joomla 2.5 with jUpgrade. jUpgrade Pro (beta software) would not work, FYI, so I had to use the original jUpgrade.  The site upgraded smoothly to joomla 2.5.

Next, I had to get the latest version of the template I was using.  When I tried to install the newer version of the YooTheme Phoenix template, it would not let me install it, saying there was already a template with that name.  I simply deleted the existing "templates\yoo_phoenix" folder, then installed the new theme again and it worked.  Afterwards, both templates (old and new) appeared in the template manager, but only the new one worked (name ending in " - Default".  I then was able to uninstall the old one.  At this point, the site was functioning perfectly.

With the new site up and running in joomla 2.5 on MySQL, I should be able to use akeeba backup to backup the site, then I restored the backup to a new site that was set up to use SQL Server.  I will update this after I've successfully restored the site to SQL Server.